# Can SQLite handle large amount of data

Tags: android, sqlite, dictionary

I will be making a mobile application in Android. My application is like Google Map's Get Direction feature, but a lot more complex, so I need to store data about points in the map. So I'm worried that SQLite may not be able to handle these large amount of data(or considering the limited storage of the phone). I have no background in SQLite so please bear with me.

Comment: What are your estimations about data size?

Comment: My map application has something to do with public transport system. For example, for a bus route, I will need to save the end points, from the starting point of the travel to the the ending point of travel and back to the starting point(if the route is not the same for the return trip). I need to save also every point where the bus will turn (corners, curve roads). I will be plotting points for more than 10 cities.

Comment: @jalbautista: ok, but how much in MB?

Comment: Sorry, I realized i didn't answer your question. More or less 50MB, I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQLite can handle large amount of data, the problem here is the device's limits. If you are going to store 3MB or more you should consider saving that data in an external server and access it via the Internet. In fact, when you are building an application that use large amount of data, usually the application don't use all data all the time, so you can save in cache (in a local database) the data that the app is currently using or is about to use.

Comment: Thanks for that. Hmmm now considering that, can I use MySQL as my external database, then ,of course, SQLite for my local database. Will that have any effect?

Comment: The only effect it will have is that you are going to have to establish an Internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to find out is to write a simple app that simulates the types of transactions you'll be doing and see how it does.

You might also want to compare how SQLite does to an object database like [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/), which is very performant and used very often as an embedded database (and can easily handle gigs of data).

Comment: The problem here is that Android supports SQLite only, and most of the devices don't have more than 1GB of internal storage.

Comment: that's not true, you can use db4o with Android: http://www.db4o.com/Android/default.aspx